# Maven can't find class even though package is included

Tags: java, maven

I have the following code:

```
package osu.cs362.URLValidator;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class DomainValidatorTest {
  RegexValidator rev = mock(RegexValidator.class);
}
```

This includes the package `osu.cs362.URLValidator` which contains `RegexValidator`.

[image]

However, when running `mvn test` I get:

> cannot find symbol class RegexValidator

Why can't it find this class?  Is this a `pom.xml` issue?

Comment: Can I ask what editor it is? I am currently using Spring Tool Suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a Maven problem.

If the `RegexValidator` class had the declaration like that :

```
package osu.cs362.URLValidator;
public class RegexValidator {
...
}
```

you would have not the problem. So I suppose it is not the case.
Besides, filesytem folders are not Java packages.

For example, nobody prevents you from declaring your class in the folder :
`osu/cs362` of your classpath folder and declaring the package of the class like that: `fictive.folder`.
The class will compile.

It is the case for `DomainValidatorTest`. The package is not symmetric with the folder layout but the class is found by the compiler and it doesn't cause a compilation error.

But of course, it is a bad practice and it is misleading. That's why packages should always be symmetric to the folders layout.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud move your `DomainValidatorTest.java` to directory:
`src/test/java/osu/cs362/URLValidator`

Directory structure should be the same as java package.